# I have trouble creating Map location hyper link using geolocation fields

Tags: formula, formula-field, geolocation, google-map

We have a requirement to create hyperlink which will take the user to the google maps page of the address.

I followed the salesforce standard solution on creating the link. as per the below link

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317670&type=1&mode=1

Also I get an error in the formula syntax :

```
HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" + IF( Property_Geolocation__c ( Property_Geolocation__Latitude__s )< 1,"0" + TEXT ( Property_Geolocation__c (Property_Geolocation__Latitude__s )), TEXT( Property_Geolocation__c (Property_Geolocation__Latitude__s )))+ "," + IF(Property_Geolocation__c ( Property_Geolocation__Longitude__s )< 1, "0" + TEXT(Property_Geolocation__c (Property_Geolocation__Longitude__s )), TEXT (Property_Geolocation__c (Property_Geolocation__Longitude__s ))),"Link")
```

Also refer to the image below.
[image]

Error: Unknown function Property_Geolocation__c. Check spelling.

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The field name format in the help article is not correct.  For example, where it says

```
IF( GeolocationFieldName (Latitude)< 1,"0"
```

You need to put in the actual API name of your latitude field.  So if your Geolocation field is named `Property_Geolocation__c` then you need

```
IF( Property_Geolocation__Latitude__s < 1,"0"
```

See the [Geolocation Compound Field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_geolocation.htm) reference page.